# TYPO3 10.4 Symfony Expression Language - class not found

Tags: classnotfound, typo3-10.x

I'm trying to customize my TypoScript conditions with Symfony Expression Language.
I've followed the instructions of the [example of typo3](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SymfonyExpressionLanguage/Index.html#sel-within-typoscript-conditions).

So i created a new file `Example_Ext/Configuration/ExpressionLanguage.php` with the example hook and also created both files `CustomTypoScriptConditionProvider.php` and `CustomConditionFunctionsProvider.php` in `Example_Ext/Classes/ExpressionLanguage`

However, as soon as I load my extension i just get the error `Class \Vendor\Example_Ext\ExpressionLanguage\CustomTypoScriptConditionProvider not found` and tbh I don't know why.
I also cleared all cache, un-/loaded the extension a couple of times and cleared the autoloader as mentioned in another thread. But it still won't work. I know that this error occurs in the first hook `ExpressionLanguage.php` because if I change the path to the file the error changes also to the new path.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Kind regards.

Comment: are you using composer?

Comment: No. I installed typo by copying the files from a zip and then used the install file of typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of debugging I found the mistake.
Apparently, it is easy to misunderstand the example

> Additional functions can be provided through another class, which has to be returned by CustomTypoScriptConditionProvider PHP class:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\TypoScript;
```

As described above I added a new file in `Example_Ext/Classes/ExpressionLanguage` but according to this code snippet, i.e., the namespace, this class has to be in `Example_Ext/Classes/TypoScript`.

Second at all I had issues with my composer.json file.
It seems some errors have prevented the autoloader to load the `Example_Ext` extension. Therefore the class could not be found additionally to the non existing class according to the namespace.

So after fixing the namespace to `Example_Ext/Classes/ExpressionLanguage` all works fine now.

Please Notice:
Custom functions with prefix `user` or `user_` are not callable.